How can fuzzy matching with an edit distance algorithm be improved when the difference in length between the two terms is significant
I am working on the implementation of the edit distance algorithm for a search bar. For example, users can search for product names with keywords like "LED Light Bulbs". The products will be ranked by the similarity of the search term and the product name. However, I've noticed that a long product name can significantly reduce its ranking.
I tried to divide the edit distance by the length of the product name, but the result still not make sense:
s = 'pie' # search term
n1 = 'pizza' # product name 1
n2 = 'apple pie' # product name 2

editDistance(s, n1) / len(n1) # 0.6
editDistance(s, n2) / len(n2) # 0.66666666

In this case, 'pizza' will rank on top of 'apple pie', which is not what I'm expecting
(I expect 'apple pie' rank higher because one term is an exact match)
I'm looking for a better approach where the length of the product name has a lower impact on the final rank.
